# access the dynamic buttons with tag

Tags: iphone

Hello I have some codes to create dynamic button as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)   
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(10+i*34 , 130+j*30, 30 , 20 );
            [button setTitle:@"00" forState:  UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:button];
           button.tag = i;  
        } 
}
```

I hope to access one dynamic button with tag

How can I do

Welcome any comment.

Thanks interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rekle stated, your views will be assigned the same tag. Use his suggestion to assign the tag `(i*100)+j`. Then to retrieve those views from another method in the same class, you can use `[UIView viewWithTag:]` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)   
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        UIButton *button = [self.view viewWithTag:(i*100)+j];
        // Do more stuff here...
    }
}
```

Here are the [Apple docs on viewWithTag](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:).

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you have is that you are setting every button created in the 'j' loop to the tag 'i'.  This means you will 8 buttons with the same tag ID.  You need to do something different with the tag based on the 'i' and 'j' indices.  Maybe something like:

```
button.tag = (i*100)+j;
```

That way you can extract the 'i' and 'j' indices from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a check like the following:

```
if (button.tag == 1) {
.....do something
}
```

or a switch statement:

```
switch (button.tag)
 {
     case 1:
          statements
          break;

     case 2:
          statements
          break;

    //more case statements

     default:
          statements
          break;
 }
```

Comment: I mean access the buttons from other function in same class

Thanks

Comment: for example, I want to change the background image of a button,
how can I get the handle of the dynamic button from other function in same class?

Thanks

Comment: do I need to store the buttons to a NSMutableArray?